# erase() does not work on a STL vector inside a structure/object?

Tags: c++, stl

I have an object that contains an STL vector. I start with the vector being size zero and use `push_back` to add to it. So, `push_back` works fine.

In my code, each element in the vector represents an atom. Thus the object this STL vector is inside is a "molecule".

When I try to remove an atom from my molecule i.e., erase one of the elements from the array, the `erase()` function does not work. Other methods do work such as `size()` and `clear()`. `clear()` removes all elements though, which is overkill. `erase()` is exactly what I want, but it doesn't work for some reason.

Here is an incredibly simplified version of my code. It does, however, represent the problem exactly.

---

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

class atomInfo 
{
/* real code has more variables and methods */
public:
    atomInfo () {} ;
};

class molInfo 
{
/* There is more than 1 atom per molecule */
/* real code has more variables and methods */
public:
    vector <atomInfo> atom;
    molInfo () {};
};

int main ()
{
    int i;
    molInfo mol;

    for( i=0; i<3 ; i++)
        mol.atom.push_back( atomInfo() );
    //mol.atom.clear() ; //Works fine
      mol.atom.erase(1) ; //does not work
}
```

---

I get the following error when I use `erase()`:

> main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’: main.cpp:39:21: error: no matching
>   function for call to ‘std::vector::erase(int)’
>        mol.atom.erase(1) ;

Comment: This will not work even if it's not "inside a structure object". This has absolutely nothing to do, whatsoever, with the vector being inside an object, or not. `erase()` does not take an `int` parameter. `erase()` takes an iterator as a parameter. See your C++ book for more information.

Comment: Which overload of vector's erase member are you expecting that to use? https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/erase

Comment: my book says name.erase(pos)    "Removes the element at the specified position"

My mistake for assuming position was given by an integer, I will look into this more and delete the question after.

Comment: Hint: mol.atom.begin() is an iterator to the first item ( if the vector is not empty).

Comment: Does the book not mention what `pos` means? Something like `iterator erase( const_iterator pos );`?

Comment: Yes, it is. We expect people to read their C++ book, from cover to cover, before they attempt to post questions here on a subject matter that's surely covered in the book. stackoverflow.com is not a substitute for a C++ book.

Comment: Remember votes for a question depend on how much we think it will be useful to help future readers.

Comment: my book only gives the one line on the erase(), and I mistook pos for meaning an integer. But fair enough, it is what it is.

Comment: I will of course delete it, but you guys did help, so thankyou for your time, downvotes and all

Comment: Good MCVE, good effort making the question, even if it was a simple rookie mistake. You probably got the downvotes for not following up on the obvious error message by looking at the docs for that function. I'll give you a +1 for making the problem clear and reproducible, which is what we're here for. It will be useful if future posters make such clear demonstrations.

Comment: Perfect MCVE though, good job with that. Too rare. Keep it up!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you thought `std::vector::erase` took an index from the start of the container.

It's not clear where you got this idea from, as it is not what [the documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/erase) says.

These functions work with *iterators*.

Fortunately, with vectors, you can get the effect you want by adding a number to an iterator.

Like this:

```
mol.atom.erase(mol.atom.begin() + 1);
```

Said documentation in fact does have an example to this effect.